# Телеграмм бот не выполняет запрос при Inline клавиатуре

Tags: python, telebot, subprocess

Запускаю бота, ''Получить скриншот'' и ''Система'' работают идеально, дошёл до браузера и всё, ловит тупняк, запрос начинает грузить, но не выполняет, причём ошибок не выдает, не знаю в чем может быть проблема.
Мой код ниже либо по этой ссылке - http://codepad.org/hsxuJLFF

```
import os
import telebot
import tempfile
import subprocess
from PIL import ImageGrab

API_TOKEN = 'Здесь токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
CDIR = os.getcwd()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Получить скриншот")
    markup.add("Система")
    markup.add("Браузер")
    markup.add("Программы")

    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b> - бот созданный для тестирования различных задач своего автора. \nby MoXiTo.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


# SCREENSHOT

@bot.message_handler(regexp='получить скриншот')
def echo_message(message):
    path = tempfile.gettempdir() + 'screenshot.png'
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
    screenshot.save(path, 'PNG')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open(path, 'rb'))

    # SCREENSHOT

# SYSTEM

@bot.message_handler(regexp='Система')
def echo_message(message):
    item1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Выключить", callback_data='system_off')
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете пункт:', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'system_off':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выключаю...')
                os.system("shutdown -s -t 0")

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

    # SYSTEM

# BROWSER

@bot.message_handler(regexp='Браузер')
def echo_message(message):
    item1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Открыть браузер", callback_data='open_browser')
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете пункт:', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'open_browser':
                subprocess.Popen([f'{CDIR}\\custom-commands\\Run browser.exe'])
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выполняю...')



    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

    # BROWSER


bot.infinity_polling()
```